# Nx + NestJS Code Coverage with Jest in e2e/integration tests

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

Hi I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
src/
├─ apps/
│  ├─ app1/
│  ├─ app1-e2e/
│  ├─ app2/
├─ libs/
│  ├─ lib1/
```

In `src/apps/app1-e2e` I have set up some integration tests for `src/apps/app1` which also implements some code from `src/libs/lib1`. These tests are written in Jest with its `jest.config.ts` running with `nx run app1-e2e`. All running good.

However, if I run `nx run app1-e2e --codeCoverage` the coverage report is generated, but it only includes what it is in `src/apps/app1-e2e`, which means the code in `src/apps/app1` and `src/libs/lib1` is not there in the report.

How can I get the rest of the code in the coverage report? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you need to put the jest config into the projects root, and then set `roots` of that config to `["apps", "libs"]`.

Adjusting the `collectCoverageFrom` might be needed as well, mine looks like `"**/!(*mock|*spec).(t|j)s"` at the moment.